# Provider Host App Error The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized in SharePoint Site

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, provider-hosted-app

When I run the app from Visual Studio, I get the page where I opt to trust the app. However, I get the 401 Unauthorized error when I try to access the app from the site.

```
Stack trace:
[WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.]
   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() +1788
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SPWebRequestExecutor.Execute() +49
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequest.ExecuteQueryToServer(ChunkStringBuilder sb) +973
   DemoAppWeb.Pages.Default.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) +401
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +109
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +68
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +4498
```

I ran the `Set-SPAppPrincipalPermission` cmd also.

Comment: Did you register the app by going to `/_layouts/15/appregnew.aspx`?  What is the line that throws the error?

Comment: Check your client ID and client secret in your app web's web.config and make sure that you are using the one you generated in appregnew.aspx

Comment: Yes I registered in appregnew.aspx

Comment: I checked already my client ID,secret, and webconfig..